# Expected an indented block Exception

Tags: csv, graph, jupyter-notebook, pyhook

After running this code, i get this exception and i didn't found any place to fix it properly

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, concat
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import ast
import csv
import sys

def plot_degree_dist(G):
in_degrees = G.in_degree()
in_degrees=dict(in_degrees)
in_values = sorted(set(in_degrees.values()))
in_hist = [in_degrees.values().count(x) for x in in_values]
plt.figure() 
plt.grid(True)
plt.loglog(in_values, in_hist, 'ro-') 
plt.plot(out_values, out_hist, 'bv-') 
plt.legend(['In-degree', 'Out-degree'])
plt.xlabel('Degree')
plt.ylabel('Number of nodes')
plt.title('network of places in Cambridge')
#plt.xlim([0, 2*10**2])
```

I expect to receive a proper graph but all i get is this warning

```
  File "<ipython-input-32-f89b896484d7>", line 2
    in_degrees = G.in_degree()
             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python relies on proper indentation to identify function blocks. This code should work:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, concat
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import ast
import csv
import sys

def plot_degree_dist(G):
    in_degrees = G.in_degree()
    in_degrees=dict(in_degrees)
    in_values = sorted(set(in_degrees.values()))
    in_hist = [in_degrees.values().count(x) for x in in_values]
    plt.figure() 
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.loglog(in_values, in_hist, 'ro-') 
    plt.plot(out_values, out_hist, 'bv-') 
    plt.legend(['In-degree', 'Out-degree'])
    plt.xlabel('Degree')
    plt.ylabel('Number of nodes')
    plt.title('network of places in Cambridge')
    #plt.xlim([0, 2*10**2])
```

Basically just indent it by 2 or 4 spaces as per your style requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!
No i got another Exception ..

AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: Great. Please feel free to mark my answer as correct so it can be useful for future users who have similar problems!

Comment: Just did! :)
Think you know what could be the solution of the new exception ?

Comment: Which line are you getting it on? I'm having trouble finding dict_values object. Would it be possible to create a new question for this and also share the error message? Official stackoverflow policy is that each question should only contain one problem! :)

Comment: Great. Share a link to the question once you create it and lets get this sorted!

Comment: It seems that i will be able to do it only an hour from now but maybe till then i'll get along!
If not, i'll post it here! 
So again - Thank you !